# Post tweet from a web site

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, tweets

I am trying to insert tweetbox plugin  to post a tweet from a website. I have followed instructions from here [http://winkpress.com/tweet-box-lets-your-visitors-write-and-send-tweets-in-your-site/][1]
[1]: http://winkpress.com/tweet-box-lets-your-visitors-write-and-send-tweets-in-your-site/
I ve added the following code, i ve inserted the consumer key,

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=[KEY]&amp;v=1"></script>
```

and

```
<div id="tbox"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 twttr.anywhere(function (T) {

 T("#tbox").tweetBox({
  height: 100,
  width: 275,
  label: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"   href="http://winkpress.com/wp-content/themes/winkpress/tweet-box.css" />Got tips,  suggestions or questions?',
defaultContent: "@winkpress "
});
});
```

I am wondering how I can achieve the connection between  box and twitter, and manage to post from the tweet box?

Comment: Well if you go to the script you are linking I think twitter might have discontinued.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome
Stopped functioning March 5th,2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter has discontinued @Anywhere. They recommend you use "Twitter for Websites" products and v1.1 REST API integrations instead of @Anywhere.

[Twitter For Websites](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites)

There you will have the option to see how to add a twitter buttons or embedded tweets to your site.

Comment: Actually, i want to sent tweets to twitter from a text box that i ve created and not from  Twitter Buttons.

Comment: I see what you want to do but you will have to find a workaround since @Anywhere is deprecated, it will not work. https://dev.twitter.com/ maybe using embedded timeline ?